# Execute task at the specified time is not work

Tags: c#, task

**I know there is lots of solutions to resolve the problem.And I want to know the reason why this code was not work,thanks.**

I'm trying to excute code at a specific hour every day.My code here:

```
    private static void RunTask(string taskName, int hour, Action act)
    {
        if (hour > 23 || hour < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("invalid hour");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var log = new Lazy<Logger>(...);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    log.Value.LogInfo($"{taskName} running at {hour} clock,{DateTime.Now}");
                    if (DateTime.Now.Hour == hour)
                        act?.Invoke();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Value.LogException(ex);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 55, 0));
            }
        });
    }

    ...
    RunTask("task",0,someAction);
    ...
```

It's supposed to excute code at 0 clock,but it's not work in windows server.This is my log content:

- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/9 9:35:59
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/9 13:07:08
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/10 19:32:50
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/11 1:36:39
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/11 14:18:07
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/11 14:55:45
- task running at 0 clock,2018/4/11 16:01:53

Comment: Use Windows Task Scheduler.  There's even a groovy API.  Better than having an expensive long-running  thread doing pretty much nothing

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler Agreed, or use some frame work like quartznet https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ . your current approach will be flakey, and never execute at the correct time

Comment: 55 minutes? That's one *sleepy* thread.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code runs at "0" clock, you sleep for 55 minutes and then run `act.Invoke()` if the DateTime.Hour == Hour. Your timing is off by a maximum of 54.999 minutes. Additionally you are writing to the log every 55 minutes, not just on the "0" hour.

Comment: what is not working is you action method doesnt get called ?

Comment: The task is not work every 55 minutes,you can see the log text.@PranayRana

Comment: best approch is to make use of System.Timer , I provided in my answer, you dont need to go to third party library

Comment: is that worked for you ??, updated answer that might help you

Comment: Also consider using Quartz.Net library for scheduled tasks - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

https://www.hangfire.io/features.html#recurring-tasks

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"), Cron.Daily);
```

You can make it work inside a windows service with the following code:
http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-windows-service.html#

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private BackgroundJobServer _server;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connection_string");
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _server = new BackgroundJobServer();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _server.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Additionally you could:

Mix it with a Self hosted .net web api to have a nice ui to monitor your tasks.

[image]

Comment: Actually,I still want to know the reason why my code was not work.

Answer (score 0):

avoid making use of `Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 55, 0));` as its blocking you and as thread context switching take place in application your thread may not fire on time you want.

you can make use of timer to execute action every 55 min by making use of Timer like as below

```
 static void Main()
   {
      Timer timer = new Timer(intvalue); //intvalue equal to 55 min
      timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => await HandleTimer();
      timer.Start();
      Console.Write("Press any key to exit... ");
      Console.ReadKey();
   }

   private static Task HandleTimer()
   {
     Console.WriteLine("\nHandler not implemented..." );
   }
```

One of the advantage of using Timer is , it get executed every 55 min  because it doesnt wait for the previous thread to do completion, means that if previous task is running more than 55 min , next elapse get fire and start executing it.

---

you can make thread await

```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
              //await for 55 min
              await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 55, 0));
        }
    });
```

this is just suggestion might help

Comment: Thanks,but it's not work for me.By the way,there is no constructor take `TimeSpan` argument in `System.Threading.Timer`

Comment: @Cyan - updated answer for that, what is your scenario , can you explaon , can try to help

Comment: I found the problem.The `Timer` is `System.Timers.Timer`,not `SystemTheading.Timer`.But,I'm using Hangfire to handle the job now.Thanks any way.